# "The multi-part identifier could not be bound" with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I've run into this problem before on another query in the past where I hadn't included the table name ahead of the query like it was expecting, but for today's problem, I'm not sure why it's throwing this error, as the table name is very clearly mentioned before the JOIN happens:

```
SELECT
  TKOPOCs.Name
  EightIDs.Email
  Cranes.CraneName
FROM
  Cranes, EightIDs
  INNER JOIN TKOPOCS
     ON Cranes.CraneID = TKOPOCs.CraneID
  INNER JOIN Mills
     ON Cranes.MILLID = Mill.MillID
WHERE EightIDs.EID = TKOPOCs.EID
```

The exception occurs or Cranes.CraneID and Cranes.MILLID but the items in the SELECT part of the query seem to work fine - it even autofills the column names when I type "Cranes." so it knows perfectly well what the Crane table is and what's in it, so what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JOIN` chains are (logically) evaluated - from left to right - before comma separated tables. Include Cranes in the join chain to make its columns available:

```
SELECT
  TKOPOCs.Name
  EightIDs.Email
  Cranes.CraneName
FROM
  Cranes
  INNER JOIN TKOPOCS
     ON Cranes.CraneID = TKOPOCs.CraneID
  INNER JOIN Mills
     ON Cranes.MILLID = Mill.MillID
  INNER JOIN EightIDs
     ON EightIDs.EID = TKOPOCs.EID
```

Comment: I'll accept as answer because it fixes the problem, but I'm curious: you're saying that, in my original query, it was looking at the join statements before it looked at the table names proceeding the FROM keyword?

Comment: For a SELECT, start with the FROM list. In the FROM list, take care of all JOIN chains first, each one from left to right. Then take care of comma separated tables. After that go to the WHERE clause etc.

Comment: Try to avoid mixing explicit joins with comma separated tables! Especially when it comes to outer joins.